# Rotate function does not update location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I have a somewhat simple script I'm trying to get working where an image will rotate to point at your cursor, and then move the image to follow the mouse once the cursor has stopped. The problem I'm having is that the rotate function which I have borrowed from another solution will not update the location of the image. Once the image moves across the screen, it still compares the original location of the image to the mouse location when calculating the rotation.

Here's my rotate function:

```
    function rotate(){
   var offset = img.offset();

   function mouse(evt) {
        var center_x = (offset.left);//(img.width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top);//(img.height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
        var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + -90;
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-moz-transform-origin', '0% 11%');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0% 13%');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform-origin', '0% 11%');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
   }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

I also have the entire project on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshbox/t8kfyxec/3/

Comment: When you say that the rotate function will not update the location of the image, which desired effect are you looking to have that is not currently happing in your jsfiddle?

Comment: perhaps just this? http://jsfiddle.net/t8kfyxec/5/ . I'm not getting if your problem is that the _offset_ variable is not update, but if it is such, just place the offset variable inside the mouse() function, so that it will be automatically updated everytime. Anyway, you don't need to use jQuery(document).ready in your fiddle.. Also, you have two mousemove listeners.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe my issue well enough. The image with the duck's finger should always point towards the cursor. It does this with the rotate function and the transform origin I added. However, once the image has moved across the screen with the move function, the rotate function no longer works reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calculating the angle of your image based on the position it has *on load* of the page, and not the current position (that may be different after it has moved).

This should be easily fixed by fetching the actual position each time you calculate the rotation angle. All you need to do is move `var offset = img.offset();` inside your `mouse()` function and it should work fine.

While you are at it, I noticed you are setting the transform origin of your image along with the angle, while the origin actually remains fixed. May I suggest you move that to your css in stead.

I went ahead and updated your fiddle with my suggestion, along with some minor readability updates: http://jsfiddle.net/t8kfyxec/6/

A few notes on the changes I made:

- It should be clearTimeout, not clearInterval
- always include the w3c standard versions (as last option), not just the ones with the browser prefixes.
- I removed the inner `move` function, as I could not see a good reason for it.
- All events are now bound inside a single event handler, and the functions that get triggered only receive the data they require, not the entire event (which makes it easier to test, debug and reuse your code)

I hope this all makes sense. Feel free to ask if you want me to explain further.

Comment: This is a huge improvement, and thank you for the thorough explanation! 

I notice that it still does not always properly track the mouse movements and will spin out of control now on occasion. Do you think this is maybe because it is refreshing ''var offset = img.offset();'' too frequently?